# Save image URI in sqllite databsae

Tags: android

Can  I store the image URI in sql DB so that I can retrieve it later to show the image? Or does it aways has to be full absolute path?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you sure can store it in the database, convert it to a string and convert it back when you want to use it

Comment: IAwesome so the uri content of image never changes right? It's like a file path

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

For example if you pick/take image, you will start the picker/camera intent, and you will get the result in `onActivityResult`, here you should get the image uri.

If the user pick from the gallery, you should do the following to get the uri.

```
String imageUri = null;
Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA}, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
if (cursor != null) {
    imageUri = cursor.getString(0);
}

cursor.close();
```

Now, save imageUri

If the user take image from the camera;

```
File photoFile = new File("your directory", "name");

Intent takePicIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePicIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
startActivityForResult(takePicIntent, ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO);
```

Then, in `onActivityResult`

```
String imageUri = photoFile.getPath();
```

And save it!

Comment: Thanks Hisham. My question was about puting URI in sqllite not how to obtain the URI